# ¿Como cambiar el ambito de las urls relativas cuando se hace un require_once?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una petición a un script index.php en el cual requiero a otro script test.php. El problema es que las urls relativas siguen partiendo del direcctorio donde está index.php y me dan error, quiero saber si se puede hacer que las urls relativas partan del directorio de test.php.

index.php:

```
<?php
$project = dirname(__FILE__);  
$project = explode('/', $project);  
$project = array_pop($project);  
require_once 'htdocs/test.php';
```

test.php

```
$img = '../images/uno.png';
echo '<img src = "'.$img.'"></img>'
```

[image: Estructura de carpetas]

Se que se soluciona poniendo la url relativa como absoluta o corrigiendo la url relativa para que encuntre la imagen pero eso no es lo que nesecito.

Comment: "Se que se soluciona poniendo la url relativa como absoluta o corrigiendo la url relativa para que encuntre la imagen pero eso no es lo que nesecito." Matizanos exactamente que es lo que necesitas, para procesar tu código de manera que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Por qué es tan necesario que no sean absolutas? Los framework más usados suelen apostar por ellas, almacenando la ruta principal en una variable a la que luego puedes concatenarle lo que más convenga. Ejemplo: **$site_url = "https://mipagina.com/"; $img = $site_url . 'images/uno.png';**

Comment: si se que absolutas mejoran hasta el rendimiento, pero eso me llevaria mucho esfuerzo para cambiarlas todas a absolutas, ten encuenta que es una solución que ya esta desarrollada, por eso quiero hacer la menor cantidad de cambios posible

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el directorio de donde parten las direcciones ralativas se usa la función chdir('htdocs') ahora todas las direcciones relativas parten de la carpera htdocs.